# OpenLayers 3 image mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I try to add on my map an image mask on the foreground, some kind of shadow frame.
The problem is that I've not been able to find a good solution to do so by trying:

- precompose/postcompose overload (drawing the image with the canvas's ctx)
- adding a layer
- adding an overlay
- adding a div over the map (events propagation issues and jQuery exceptions)

Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Something like in [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/layer-clipping.html)?

Comment: Yes something like that but with a SVG image like [this](http://safari.am/images/frame_shadow.png).
I've tried this example by replacing the bezier by an image drawing, but as my map is refresh frequently (moving points) the are artifacts a each redraw

Comment: I've modified this example [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/k34t4xw4/1/) but I've have artifacts when moving the map

Comment: @tsauerwein Fixed in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6j1mu80/1/). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to bind on `postcompose` event.
Here is the JS code making it working:

```
    var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [osm],
      target: 'map',
      controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
          collapsible: false
        })
      }),
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 5
      })
    });

    var image = new Image();
    var loaded = false;
    image.src = 'http://safari.am/images/frame_shadow.png';
    image.onload = function() {
        loaded = true;
    };

    osm.on('postcompose', function(event) {
        var ctx = event.context;
        if(loaded)
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();
    });
```

You can find the full solution in the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6j1mu80/1/)